# Colour of the terminal prompt lost

Tags: linux-mint, terminal

The terminal inside Linux Mint had a default colour scheme that helped to easily identify the prompt (that contained the username and the machine name). But after installing drush, the command line tool for configuring Drupal, the prompt lost its default colour. How can I revert it?

I was asked in the comments to display the difference in the .bashrc files before and after installing drush. I have included the difference as the code below.

```
# Path to Drush, added by 'drush init'.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/local-sites/drupal-8.4.3/vendor/bin"


# Include Drush bash customizations.
if [ -f "/home/user/.drush/drush.bashrc" ] ; then
      source /home/user/.drush/drush.bashrc
fi

# Include Drush completion.

if [ -f "/home/user/.drush/drush.complete.sh" ] ; then
      source /home/user/.drush/drush.complete.sh
fi

# Include Drush prompt customizations.

if [ -f "/home/user/.drush/drush.prompt.sh" ] ; then
  source /home/user/.drush/drush.prompt.sh
fi
```

Comment: From what I can read here [http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/] , `drush init` modify the bash configuration file `~/.bashrc`. So you can have a look there and compare it with `/etc/skel/.bashrc` or similar default one.

Comment: @baselab I did check it and all I was able to find was that drush appends a few lines to the bashrc. I'll try to include the additional lines drush added to the file in the question description.

Answer (score 0):

Drush has it's own prompt color settings which override whatever is in ~./bashrc. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and restored the colors by modifying ~/drush.prompt.sh, changing the PROMPT_COMMAND line from

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\u@\h \w" "$(__drush_ps1 "[%s]") \\\$ "'
```

to

```
 export PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]" "$(__drush_ps1 "[%s]") \\\$ "'
```

I don't know if these colors match what Mint uses.